# Evaluation of a limit involving gamma function

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, gamma-function

Basically I try to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4739300/compute-gamma-lim-n-to-infty-int-t-nt-n1-fracfx-t-ngt/4740372#4740372). I am almost able to prove it straight on, but I hit a roadblock at the very last step. Namely, the limit
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left( \sqrt[n+1]{\Gamma \left( n+1+\frac{1}{2} \right)}-\sqrt[n]{\Gamma \left( n+\frac{1}{2} \right)} \right) 
$$
It should evaluate to $1/e$ through numerical estimation. One possible direction here is to justify that we just plug in Stirling's formula, due to
$$
\sqrt[n]{\Gamma \left( n+\frac{1}{2} \right)}\sim \frac{n}{e}
$$
we have
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left( \sqrt[n+1]{\Gamma \left( n+1+\frac{1}{2} \right)}-\sqrt[n]{\Gamma \left( n+\frac{1}{2} \right)} \right) =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{n+1}{e}-\frac{n}{e} \right) =\frac{1}{e}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: [Stirling's approximation](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Stirling%27s_approximation)
$$\ln \Gamma(t) = t\ln t - t -\frac12\ln t + \frac12 \ln(2\pi)  + O\left(\frac1t\right)$$

Comment: Got it, use the expansion, Lagrange Mean Value theorem and squeeze theorem.