# $T=\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt [n+1] {n!}}}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt [n+1]{(n-1)!}}} \frac{n+1}{x(n+1)ln(x)+xln((n+1)!)} \,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Compute $T$ for $n>0$;
> $$T=\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt [n+1] {n!}}}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt [n+1]{(n-1)!}}} \frac{n+1}{x(n+1)ln(x)+xln((n+1)!)} \,dx$$

My attempts;

Whatever I have tried was along the lines of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4739300/1157207);

Apart from that,

$$T=\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt [n+1] {n!}}}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt [n+1]{(n-1)!}}} \frac{1}{x\left[ln(x)+\frac{1}{n+1}ln((n+1)!)\right]} \,dx$$

Putting $\frac{1}{n+1}ln((n+1)!)=t$

$$T=\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt [n+1] {n!}}}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt [n+1]{(n-1)!}}} \frac{1}{x\left[ln(x)+t\right]} \,dx$$

Ignoring the limit and the bounds as noise, you get;

$$T= \int \frac{1}{x\left[ln(x)+t\right]} \,dx$$

Substitute $ln(x)=u$ and simplifying,

$$T=ln(ln(x)+t)$$

$$T=ln\left[ln(x)+\frac{1}{n+1}ln((n+1)!)\right]_{\frac{1}{\sqrt [n+1] {n!}}}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt [n+1]{(n-1)!}}}$$

$$T=ln\left[ln\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt [n+1]{(n-1)!}}\right)+\frac{1}{n+1}ln((n+1)!)\right]-ln\left[ln\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt [n+1] {n!}}\right)+\frac{1}{n+1}ln((n+1)!)\right]$$

$$T=\lim_{n \to \infty} ln\left[ln\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt [n+1]{(n-1)!}}\right)+\frac{1}{n+1}ln((n+1)!)\right]-ln\left[ln\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt [n+1] {n!}}\right)+\frac{1}{n+1}ln((n+1)!)\right]$$

But I hit a dead-end here. Although it is unnecessary (I think), I reading about convergence tests just to check its convergence but could not apply it to conclude anything. If my work was right, how do I proceed from here? I am thinking use of Stirling approximation.

> Also what is the best method to approach this/such kind of
> limits?

Comment: oh, I can't resist on limits and integrals.

Comment: Good to see you again :), (indian?),

Comment: Hopefully yes! And your name suggests that you're too..

Comment: It is really terrifying limit :'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did seems correct. To continue

$\ln \left[\ln\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt[n+1]{(n-1)!}}\right)  + \frac{1}{n+1} \ln((n+1)!)\right] -  \ln \left[\ln\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt[n+1]{n!}}\right)  + \frac{1}{n+1} \ln((n+1)!)\right]$
$= \ln\left(\frac{\ln\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt[n+1]{(n-1)!}}\right)  + \frac{1}{n+1} \ln((n+1)!)}{\ln\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt[n+1]{n!}}\right)  + \frac{1}{n+1} \ln((n+1)!)}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{\ln\left( \frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[n+1]{(n-1)!}}\right)  }{\ln\left( \frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[n+1]{n!}}\right)  }\right) = \ln\left(\frac{\ln\left( {\sqrt[n+1]{\frac{(n+1)!}{(n-1)!}}}\right)  }{\ln\left( {\sqrt[n+1]{\frac{(n+1)!}{n!}}}\right)  }\right)$
$=\ln\left(\frac{\frac{1}{n+1}\ln\left( n(n+1)\right)  }{\frac{1}{n+1}\ln\left( n+1\right)   }\right)=\ln\left(\frac{\ln\left( n(n+1)\right)  }{\ln\left( n+1\right)   }\right)=\ln\left(1+\frac{\ln\left( n\right)  }{\ln\left( n+1\right)   }\right)$

$\Rightarrow T = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\ln\left(1+\frac{\ln\left( n\right)  }{\ln\left( n+1\right)   }\right)}=\ln(2)$

Comment: @ayan This post *is* most of the proof...The limit was not taken until the very end of the manipulations. How formally you wish to take it was not specified by you at all. It comes across as you couldn't be bothered to apply basic properties of limits yourself after all this work was already done for you.

Comment: @ayan Doesn't the last line show you what value the limit equals?

Comment: @Accelerator clearly I have been learning limits the wrong way, thank you